# What is the cause of the error "Remote host closed connection during handshake"?

Tags: database, oracle, ssl

I want connect to the Oracle database 11.2 with SSL. But the only error that I receive is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: I/O-Fehler: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:465)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:534)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:217)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:28)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:527)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at TestOracle.testSSL(TestOracle.java:157)
    at TestOracle.main(TestOracle.java:131)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:808)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:420)
    at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:169)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:301)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1406)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:327)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    ... 16 more
```

I have add a self signed certificate to a created wallet. But I does not understand how the Oracle server can use it because it need a password which the oracle server does not know. Must I see the password and where must I set it?

On the network I can see that the Oracle server does not send any bytes. It close the socket after the client has start the handshake. That I think the problem is on the server side.

My listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora11.inetsoftware.local)(PORT = 1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ora11.inetsoftware.local)(PORT = 2484))
)
)

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator

WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\BIN\owm\wallets\Administrator)))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
```

My sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\BIN\owm\wallets\Administrator)))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It is very simple. First you need set auto login. This creates a file cwallet.sso in the wallet directory. And the most important thing is that you have closed the wallet in the wallet manager when you start the TNS listener service. Else the listener can not load the file cwallet.sso. In the trace file you can see the error:

```
ntzlogin:Wallet open failed with error 28759
```

If you close the wallet later, this has no effect. It looks like the listener read the file only once.

Comment: Hi @Horcrux7 , facing the same issue with same Exception message, but couldn't understand your solution -"closed the wallet in the wallet manager when you start the TNS listener service." What do you refer by Wallet Manager, which file you suggest to close. None of my server or client wallet certificates are opened in any editor. Please suggest some resolution for my case.

Comment: If you have not opened the wallet then you have not the same problem. Look into the trace file if the TNS listener write some errors.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate doesn't have a password. The thing the certificate is in has a password. Your client knows the password, gets the certificate outcof the thing, sends the certificate to the server.

If the server doesn't like the  certificate for some reason, it may then close the connection rather than continuing the handshake. Same if you don't send it on request, which would happen if your certificate doesn't satisfy the constraints specified by the server in the certificate request. For example, if the server doesn't recognize the self-signer. Have you exported the certificate to the server's trust store?

Comment: The client does not know the certificate else the password of the wallet. What you means with trust store? The self signet certificate is only stored in a password protected wallet.

Comment: @Horcrux7 I don't understand your first sentence. The server has a repository somewhere of certificate signers that it trusts. If the self-signer isn't in that repository the server won't trust it. If the certificate was signed by a CA you wouldn't have a problem, but you have chosen to use a self-signed certificate so it is up to you to get peers to trust it. If you don't know what that means, you're far better off paying the fifty bucks and getting it signed by a recognized CA.

Comment: Aha, I have thing that the wallet is the store of trusted certificates. On the MS SQL Server there is only one store. All certificates that I store in it are trusted.

Comment: @Horcrux7 yes but have you stored *all* the trusted certificates into it? It's not the same thing.